# Laravel how to query parent relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Model `ScheduledProgram` that belongs to `ProgramSession`

I want to change the query below to replace `registration_start_date` (from `ScheduledProgram`) with `registration_start` (from `ProgramSession`). I.E. I want to change the query to get the field from its parent model instead of itself.

```
  $programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
                                    ->where('end_date', '>=',  $today)
                                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$programs = ScheduledProgram::whereHas('programSession', function($query) use ($today) {
    return $query->where('registration_start', '>=', $today)
        ->where('end_date', '>=',  $today)
})
->get();
```